# Discord.Net how to get a reaction from a message

Tags: c#, discord

Together with my team we write a bot. I don't know how to get a reaction from a message when someone adds it. From the reaction I would like to get pieces of information about the user who added the reaction, to which message the reaction was added, what reaction was added, when the reaction was added and what message it was. How to do it?

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: What have you tried to far? How about `message.Reactions`? That seems to be the only data the Discord API provides

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it.